# $u+v$ is orthogonal to $u-v$ if and only if $\|u\| = \|v\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

I'm doing an introductory linear algebra course and I'm stuck on this question.

Show that with respect to any inner product, $u+v$ is orthogonal to $u-v$ if and only if $\|u\| = \|v\|$.

I'm trying to prove the forward implication and I don't know where to go from
$\langle u+v,u-v \rangle=0$

I tried working with the cosine formula or with the fact that $\langle u+v,u-v \rangle = \langle u-v,u+v \rangle$ but I don't really know where I'm going...

Could someone show me how to prove both forward and backward implications?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the linearity of the inner product, $\langle a+b,c\rangle=\langle a,c\rangle+\langle b,c\rangle$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

Expand the inner product using the linearity rules (twice): $\langle a + b, c \rangle = \langle a,c\rangle + \langle b,c\rangle$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You can start like this:
$\langle u+v,u-v\rangle =0$ $\Leftrightarrow$
 
$\langle u+v,u\rangle - \langle u+v,v\rangle=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$
Can you take it from there? (At some place you will have to use that $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle v,u\rangle$ and that $\langle u,u\rangle = \|u\|^2$.)

Answer (score 0):

If **u+v** is orthogonal to **u-v**,

(**u+v**).(**u-v**)=**u.u - v.v** = 0 by dot product and by definition of orthogonal,
Hence, **u.u=v.v**.

But **u.u=||u||^2** and **v.v=||v||^2**

Hence, **||u||^2**=**||v||^2**

It follows that **||u||=||v||** or **||u||=-||v||** (But it cannot be negative so we reject the latter answer).
Therefore, we have **||u||=||v||**.

Now because this is if and only if, so we have to show that if *p*, then *q*. AND if *q*, then *p*.

Hence now we show that if **||u||=||v||**, then **u+v** is orthogonal to **u-v**,

Applying the same concept because we are lazy people :),

**||u||^2=||v||^2**

**||u||^2-||v||^2=0** which is the same as **u.u - v.v = 0** and factorizing it will produce

**(u + v)(u - v) = 0**. By definition of orthogonal, **u+v** is orthogonal to **u-v**.

Proven